# repositories vs pluginRepositories in maven settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have the below settings.xml file in my **~/.m2/** folder:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>my-repositories</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>thirdparty-repository</id>
                    <name>Thirdparty repository</name>
                    <url>https://mynexus/repository/thirdparty/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>thirdparty-plugin-repository</id>
                    <name>Thirdparty plugin repository</name>
                    <url>https://mynexus/repository/thirdparty/</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>my-repositories</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

For both repositories the same nexus group repository is used:

https://mynexus/repository/thirdparty/

If I remove the first one: `thirdparty-repository` I get the below error:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.8.2: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.8.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Now If I re-enable it and instead remove the other one: `thirdparty-plugin-repository` I now get this error:

```
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Only when I have them both enabled at the same time it works.

Why do I need both `repositories` and `pluginRepositories` that points to the same nexus repository?

Comment: You seemed to be having an issue with certificates: unable to find valid certification path to requested targe

Comment: Yes but why don't I get that error when I enable both repos?

Comment: Because the dependencies can't be resolved based on the mentioned error.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you had defined a plugin with some dependencies. These dependencies will be searched in all of your `<pluginRepository>` definitions. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
   <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.herd.common</groupId>
          <artifactId>common-herd</artifactId>
          <version>${common.version}</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Even if you have a `<repository>` defined which contains the **common-herd** artifact, Maven will not downloaded it unless you also have a `<pluginRepository>` containing it. And of course, the **common-herd** artifact can not be present inside the Maven Central Repository.

I had this problem a few months ago and Maven only downloaded the specific plugin dependency after I added a `<pluginRepository>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a pb like this, idk if it will help but with this code in my POM.xml my nexus pb were resolved

```
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>releases</name>
        <url>https://mynexus/repository/thirdparty/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://mynexus/repository/thirdparty/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and

```
        <!-- download artifacts from this repo -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>Public</name>
        <url>https://mynexus/repository/thirdparty/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>

        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

In Nexus there is defined a public group which should contain all needed repositories and there should no need to configure this in your  own pom nor in the settings.xml file. Only the public group of Nexus should be configured

The only thing you need is to change the url in mirror with your own location...

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Why do I need to add a mirror? Can't I just add the repositories I need, they are in nexus anyway.